# TFTP timeout inside Docker container

Tags: docker, unix, networking, udp, tftp

I have a **Docker container** with **tftp client** on Host#1 with IP 10.10.10.10.
I have a **file** and a **tftp server** on Host#2 with IP 11.11.11.11

I want to be able to download file from Host#2 with this tftp client inside Docker container.

The main problem is that tftp uses port 69 only as a **control port**, but sends data on **ephemeral** ports. Thus, I tftp client is able to ask the server to send the file, but then can't receive the file itself and catches **timeout**.

**So how do I download this file with tftp?**

I know **two** solutions for now.
First, using `--net=host`. I do not want to use it because of security (and not only) concerns. Second, **publishing** ephemeral ports 49152-65535. It's hard to make it work if anything else on host uses any of these ephemeral ports.

Also, it is everything fine with Firewall!

Comment: @danielRicado Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to resolve this otherwise than to move away from TFTP

Comment: hey I found out it's a windows problem. using alpine:latest, ports 69:69/udp and network mode not set / default it began working. turns out the issue is with windows/wsl2 and its ability to provide a port. Once I tested it directly on a pi running debian it all worked just fine. So the mystery at least in my case was the windows environment